# Xamarin Forms, Detecting map Scrolling, Zooming and etc event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms Maps official nuget library, everything works good and I handle **finish** zooming and scrolling map via this code:

```
map.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var m = sender as Map;
            if (m?.VisibleRegion == null) return;
            SearchButton.IsVisible = true;
        };
        map.PropertyChanging += (sender, args) => { SearchButton.IsVisible = false; };
```

But I want to do some stuff when user **starts** scrolling or zooming map!
I didn't find it and also `PropertyChanging` not called when user is surfing the map, it's calling just before `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

I think in Xamarin.Forms your options are limited, so your best option would be to either create a custom renderer and abstract the gestures into Xamarin.Forms, or create your own custom canvas, render the map onto it and that way you would have full control.